# Custom Django login form middleware

Tags: django, django-middleware, django-1.11

I'm looking at a solution of implementing a modal pop-up login form to be used site wide in the navigation bar. I'm working with Django 1.11. Now, I'm defining a LoginFormMiddleware class as follows:

**middleware.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class LoginFormMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_request(self, request):
        from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
        if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.has_key('base-account') and request.POST['base-account'] == 'Login':
            form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST, prefix="login")
            if form.is_valid():
                from django.contrib.auth import login
                login(request, form.get_user())
            request.method = 'GET'
        else:
            form = AuthenticationForm(request, prefix="login")
        request.login_form = form
```

This is all included in the standard way in settings.py in `MIDDLEWARE = []`. I also have 'django.template.context_processors.request' defined in `TEMPLATES = [ { ... 'OPTIONS': { 'context_processors': [ *** ] } ]` as I should.

Using `{{ request.login_form }}` in my templates as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  {{ request.login_form }}
</div>
```

Yet nothing is being rendered - where it should? From browser inspector tools:

[image]

Can anyone advise me on what I am missing please?

Full middleware list:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'wagtail.wagtailcore.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
    'wagtail.wagtailredirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
    'thinkingplace.middleware.LoginFormMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: are you sure that you have the middleware properly configured? try printing a hello world if it works

Comment: @MauricioCortezar Where’s best to add that, in the else statement?

Comment: after the def process_request function

Comment: Nothing in terminal...

Comment: so, your middleware isn't working, the hello world should appear when you reload a page

Comment: So what have I missed? I’ve included it in settings.py ...

Comment: Do I need Django auth login View in urls?

Comment: Is it process_view in Django 1.11?

Comment: can you show the middleware list?

Comment: Sure, *added to question*

Comment: it should work, make sure is the right path

Comment: Yep, it's in the app named "thinkingplace" in middleware.py ...

Comment: What else could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process_request` is from the old-style, pre-Django 1.10 middleware. You are using new-style middleware so Django will not call that method.

You could move that code to the `__call__` method before you call `get_response`.

```
def __call__(self, request):
    # code that sets request.login_form
    return self.get_response(request)
```

However, I’m not sure that using a middleware is the best approach here. I would consider creating a context processor that adds the login form to the template context, then submit login requests to a single login view.

Comment: That’s complex. So, process_view() ??

Comment: Although process_template_response() looks ok?

Comment: `process_view` would be an option. `process_template_response` is not the right hook to use.

Comment: Awesome, that works. I'm wondering if this is efficient, it seems to have cycled three times through the __call__ function? (It's printed "Hello, world!" x3 for each request-response cycle)

Comment: I’m not sure where you called `print()`, but the `__call__` method should only be called once per request:

Comment: Ok I had three requests when loading the home page - still not efficient. Will have to think about a better method perhaps?

Comment: As I said, I don’t know where you put `print()`. Loading the home page should be a single request, submitting the form a second, and if you redirect after a successful login you get a third request.